# unable to get data from the database in a JTable?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i'm trying to display the data of a table in the form of a `JTable`.
My table is in `Oracle 10g Express Edition`.
T.name: Doctor
I want that the entire table should be displayed in my form with the help of a JTable.

```
class PatientTableFromDatabase extends JFrame
{
    static Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    PatientTableFromDatabase()
    {
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();
        Vector data = new Vector();

        try
        {
            //  Connect to the Database
            try{

                //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                //cn=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:pat");
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe", "hr", "hr");
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //  Read data from a table

            String sql = "Select * from Doctor";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
            }

            //  Get row data

            while (rs.next())
            {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }

                data.addElement( row );
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println( e );
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //  Create table with database data

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

          /*  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
         getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );*/
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PatientTableFromDatabase frame = new PatientTableFromDatabase();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

when i run the frame appears but with no data,no table.
Please Help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you sql query is empty

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(  );
```

try with

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(  sql);
```

Comment: corrected it but then also same thing,only frame appears,no table,no data.And in cmd java.lang.NullPointerException after quitting.

Comment: @user3367768 print the stacktrace

Comment: I got this
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at PatientTableFromDatabase.<init><PatientTableFromDatabase.java:55>
       at PatientTableFromDatabase.main<PatientTableFromDatabase.java:106>

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables called `con`

The first one is the static one defined at the top of your class, and then you define it again in your `try-catch` block on line 21.

On line 34 you are using the uninitialized version of `con` and therefore you get the NullPointerException.

To fix this issue change the code to the following:

```
...
try{
    //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    //cn=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:pat");
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe", "hr", "hr");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
...
```